# Transfer learning CNNs for image classification in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

This code works, and I'm pretty sure it's mathematically/algorithmically correct:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(include_top=False,input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
model.trainable = False
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    model,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        1, "sigmoid"
    ),
])

try:
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
                  metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve="PR")])

    model.fit(train_dataset,
              epochs=2,
              validation_data=validation_dataset)
finally:
    for directory in tempdirs:
        rmtree(directory)
```

For completion, here is my dataset setup and imports, I'm being very verbose and not using [`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) and/or builtin random dataset utility functions, to keep things like my real workflow:

```
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from os import path, mkdir
from shutil import rmtree
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

NUM_CLASSES = 2
INPUT_SHAPE = 256, 256, 3


def create_random_ds(tempdir):
    for class_num in range(NUM_CLASSES):
        directory = path.join(tempdir, 'class{}'.format(class_num))
        mkdir(directory)
        for i in range(20):
            Image \
              .fromarray((np.random.rand(*INPUT_SHAPE) * 255).astype('uint8')) \
              .convert('RGBA') \
              .save(path.join(directory, 'image{}.png'.format(i)))

    return tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        tempdir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    )

tempdirs = mkdtemp(), mkdtemp()

train_dataset = create_random_ds(tempdirs[0])
validation_dataset = create_random_ds(tempdirs[1])
```

---

What do you think, is it correct, and how can it be improved?